# std::move with a unique pointer of a base class pointing to an instance of a derived class

Tags: c++, c++11, design-patterns, smart-pointers, unique-ptr

I am attempting to implement the command and strategy design patterns in C++.

I have an interface for a command, and an interface for a strategy (a different strategy is assigned to each player, so a player may be manual, AI aggressive, AI defensive, AI random... etc). The strategies have a series of functions which return a unique pointer of type ICommand (eg the command interface) which point to an instance of a derived command class. The idea is to create some command in my strategy in a particular way, and then return the unique pointer to the particular command to the game (the invoker of commands) which execute the commands, regardless of what that command is.

My following questions are these:

- if I move an instance of a derived class which is pointed to by a unique pointer of a base class, will I get object slicing?
- if so, what would be a better way of handling moving around objects regardless of their type ?

Here is my code. Note that I only included the code for the command `choose_combo`, as the rest would be somewhat redundant:

I have an interface for my standard command:

```
class Igame_command {
protected: // protected, since Igame_command is an interface.
    player &p;
    game_model &gm;

    Igame_command(player p, game_model gm) : p(p), gm(gm) {}

public:
    virtual void execute() = 0;
};
```

I then have some derived class which implements the above interface:

```
class choose_combo_c : private Igame_command {
    combo c;
    int vp;
public:
    void set_combo(combo c) { this->c = c; }
    void set_vp(int vp) { this->vp = vp; }
    combo get_combo() { return c; }
    int get_vp() { return vp; }
    choose_combo_c::choose_combo_c(player &p, game_model &gm);

    void execute() override;
};
```

I then have an interface for my strategy:

```
class Istrategy {
protected:
application &app;
game_model &gm;
player &p;

Istrategy(application &app, game_model &gm, player &p) : app(app), gm(gm), p(p) {}

public:

virtual std::unique_ptr<Igame_command> choose_combo(
        std::vector<combo> &available_combos, std::vector<int> &available_combos_vp) = 0;

};
```

For example, for the manual strategy, choosing combo:

```
std::unique_ptr<Igame_command> manual_strategy::choose_combo(
        std::vector<combo> &available_combos, std::vector<int> &available_combos_vp) override {

    // code to have the player make a choice, it sets the int choice...    

    choose_combo_c* ccc = new choose_combo_c(p, gm);
    ccc->set_combo(available_combos.at(choice));
    ccc->set_vp(available_combos_vp.at(choice));
    return std::unique_ptr<Igame_command> (new choose_combo_c(std::move(*ccc)));
}
```

Comment: Slicing can happen only during copying into a base class. Reassigning pointers can never cause slicing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`unique_ptr<T>` stores a `T*`, not a `T`, so you won't get any object slicing in your example.

But you do have a memory leak, the `ccc` object you allocate is not being `delete`d by anyone, you're move constructing a new object from it, but leaking the original itself. The code within `manual_strategy::choose_combo` should be written as

```
auto ccc = std::make_unique<choose_combo_c>(p, gm);  // create a unique_ptr<choose_combo_c>
// do stuff with it
ccc->set_combo(available_combos.at(choice));
ccc->set_vp(available_combos_vp.at(choice));

// simply return it here, a unique_ptr<Igame_command>
// will be constructed from the unique_ptr<choose_combo_c>
return ccc;
```

Comment: If I use your example, whilst avoiding the leak you mention, the 'auto' creates a unique pointer of type choose_combo_c, not Igame_command. Since the functions I use after on ccc  (set_combo(), set_vp() ) are from the derived class choose_combo_c, I also can't immediately declare it as Igame_command...

Comment: @Gathaspa Yes, is that a problem?

Answer (score 0):

You can't "move" raw pointers - not meaningfully, anyway. You can meaningfully move a `unique_ptr`, but that doesn't move the object anywhere, it only means that the ownership of that pointed-to object (as allocated memory) moves to someplace/someone else.

That's not what you're doing, though; your code moves your temporary object into a newly-allocated object (which causes a memory leak, as @Preatorian  [points out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49616919/1593077)).

> What would be a better way of handling moving around objects regardless of their type ?

Working with pointers *is* actually a reasonable way for doing object "moves"  irrespective of their types: You simply never (or rarely) actually move any objects, you only work with pointers to them. You might not be able to use typed `unique_ptr`s if you want type-obliviousness, but you could use `void *` or `unique_ptr<void>` pointers with custom deleters.

Another alternative is to use `std::any`'s, without pointers. If the objects are small, moving these is cheap, and if they're big, they're hiding pointers inside, so moving them is again cheap. This alternative in safer in the sense that instead of segmentation violation and reinterpreting garbage, you'll just get exceptions if you try the wrong type.